# How to clone an ember-cli project?

Tags: ember-cli

I am trying to test some [Broccoli debugging](http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2015/02/02/debugging-a-broccoli-tree.html). For that I do:

```
» git clone https://github.com/rwjblue/debugging-broccoli.git
» cd debugging-broccoli
» ember init # I am asked here about overwriting some files. I say no
» ember serve
```

And I am greeted with:

```
version: 0.1.11
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the serve command.
```

So, maybe it was not `ember init`, but `ember install` (whatever, `ember init` seems like the right command to initialize a cloned repository, but I digress ...). So I try `ember install` (with a fresh clone, just in case):

```
» git clone https://github.com/rwjblue/debugging-broccoli.git
» cd debugging-broccoli
» ember install
version: 0.1.11
You have to be inside an ember-cli project in order to use the install command.
```

So, how can I clone and serve an exisiting ember-cli repo?

### Note

Strangely enough, in my application repo I have a different version of ember-cli:

```
» ember --version
version: 0.1.12
node: 0.10.25
npm: 2.1.8
```

I though ember-cli was installed globally ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ember-cli -g is only for command line, you need it local. Use npm and bower install after cloning.

Comment: Does not work in the linked repo. Can you try that and report what you get?

Comment: Mmmm, you are right, my bad. It is a broccoli project, which do not know how to run ...

Comment: are you serious guys?! :'(